# EULA License Agreement Dialog not displayed while Upgrade

Tags: windows-installer, installshield, eula

Using windows installer, the `EULA License Agreement` Dialog box is displayed when we are installing it for very first time. But while `upgrading` it is not displayed so how can we do that.

I have found one question for this. 
[how to show EULA during upgrade using installshield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18246114/how-to-show-eula-during-upgrade-using-installshield/18594996#18594996). But the answer didn't looks satisfactory.

Comment: What's unsatisfactory about the other answer? The only other suggestion I would have is to create a major upgrade instead of a minor upgrade. A major upgrade acts more like a first-time installation.

Comment: That is not actually working. After doing the changes, still no EULA dialog appears.

Comment: what do yo mean by "no EULA dialog appears"? EULA screen licence is blank screen or entire screen got skipped?